# regex with an end alpha which is optional

Tags: regex

I'm very new to regex and trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to validate a string that:

1. starts with anyone of these `abcdjklmnpqrstwz`
2. followed by either 1 or 2 alpha
3. followed by 1 to 4 ints
4. Optional: Ends with a single alpha

here is my regex 
 `/(^[abcdjklmnpqrstwz](:?[a-z]{1,2})) [0-9]{1,4} *([a-z]{1})/i`

here is some sample of string that should be true

```
bab 1234 a

bab 1234

bab 123

b 123 a
```

[click here to test](http://regex101.com/r/xP7hU9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following regex:

```
/^[a-dj-np-twz](?:[a-z]{1,2})?\s[0-9]{1,4}(?:\s[a-z])?$/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP7hU9/4)!

Comment: `bab 1234a` should be false, must have a space before the `a`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `?` instead of `{1}` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/rH2nG6/1)):

```
/(^[abcdjklmnpqrstwz](:?[a-z]{1,2})) [0-9]{1,4} ([a-z]?)/i
```

The `?` specifies that the preceding block is optional.

Comment: `bab 1234a` should be false, must have a space before the `a`

Comment: It wasn't specified in the request, but just remove the `*`, or use a `+` if you want to allow "at least one"